# How to search by array values in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have an array: **ARRAY['one','mon','uuuu','wed','thu','fri','qwer']**
and query:

```sql
select * from table t where t.name like ARRAY[i]
```

how could I iterate query with ARRAY values and save results into some output?

I mean to get results of:

```sql
select * from table t where t.name like 'one'
select * from table t where t.name like 'mon'
select * from table t where t.name like 'uuuu'
...
select * from table t where t.name like 'qwer'
```

and save them for example into the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to [`unnest`](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_unnest-function.php) the array in a subquery or [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) and apply the expression you want, e.g.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (name text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('mon'),('qwer'),('mon'),('xpto');

WITH j (val) AS (
 SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['one','mon','uuuu','wed','thu','fri','qwer'])
) SELECT * FROM j,t WHERE t.name LIKE j.val;

 val  | name 
------+------
 mon  | mon
 mon  | mon
 qwer | qwer
(3 Zeilen)
```

If you need to use `%` in your `LIKE`, just concatenate it to the string with `||`, e.g.

```
WITH j (val) AS (
 SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['one','mon','uuuu','wed','thu','fri','qwer'])
) SELECT * FROM j,t WHERE t.name LIKE '%' || j.val || '%';
```

Or use the [`ANY`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-any/) operator

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE name LIKE ANY(ARRAY['one','mon','uuuu','wed','thu','fri','qwer']);
 name 
------
 mon
 qwer
 mon
(3 Zeilen)
```